# X11 drawing on resize

Tags: c, x11, xlib

I want to use x11 in order to draw graphics which require heavy computation. A graph is drawn 3-4 seconds and I want it to fit in the window. Therefore it has to be redrawn on resizes. However every resize sends several `ConfigureNotify` messages. As the program execution should not stop while drawing, I create another thread.

However each time a window is resized, several threads are created and my graphic gets messy. What should I do? There were answers to similar questions which suggested to start drawing only when there are no pending `ConfigureNotify` events, but I don't quite understand how to get the next event without dropping the current one. Another solution was to use a timer to redraw in fixed intervals, but in my case the intervals are too big. And I want the graphic and the inscriptions to be drawn separately, so that the user could get all the nesesary information while the graphic is being processed.

I am new to GUI and do not understand how are such cases dealt with.